# How to play a sound notification with Chrome for Android with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

Playing a MP3 with

```js
var popsound = new Audio('http://gget.it/u1urz3zh/popsound.mp3');
popsound.load();
popsound.play();
```

doesn't work in Chrome for Android. According to [this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132), this is a feature, to not allow playback this way, i.e. without explicit user input.

**I understand that this is done on purpose (to save mobile data for the user, mainly), but then how to make a website play a notification sound?** There surely is a way to play notification sounds (notifications are popular on phone), how to do it?

---

**If not possible, at least, how to know (with JS) if the browser will be allowed or not allowed to play sound with `.play()`?** (then it will be possible to show if sound notifications are available or not on the website)

---

Context : I'm creating a [web chat service](https://github.com/josephernest/talktalktalk), then how to play a sound notification after a message is posted if I cannot use `.play()` in Chrome for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least this trick allows to know in advance if media playback requires user gesture:

```
function mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture() { 
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.play();
  return audio.paused;
}
```

[Found here.](https://blog.foolip.org/2014/02/10/media-playback-restrictions-in-blink/)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in my app. My application usage scenario was like this:
1) click the button to show a table with information (user action)
2) show the table and refresh data in it by AJAX
3) play sound when data has been changed 
Fortunatelly I had the user action (step 1) so I was able to "initiate" the sound by it and then play it by javascript without the user action needed. See the code.

HTML

```
<audio id="kohoutAudio">
    <source src="views/images/kohout.mp3">
</audio>

<button id="btnShow">Show table</button>
```

Javascript

```
$("#btnShow").click(function () {
    //some code to show the table
    //initialize the sound
    document.getElementById('kohoutAudio').play();
    document.getElementById('kohoutAudio').pause();
    });

function announceChange(){
    document.getElementById('kohoutAudio').play();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, Chrome browser in Android now has a permissions options page that allows the user to set autoplay option. Not sure if this helps on your end.

I have attached pictures from Android Chrome browser settings:
[image: after clicking on the lock of the address bar]
[image: the hidden permissions settings]

Answer (score -1):

You can add an audio element to the DOM and change it dynamically via javascript.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('audio').src = 'http://gget.it/u1urz3zh/popsound.mp3';
   document.getElementById('audio').load();
   document.getElementById('audio').play();
  }, 2000);
```

```html
<audio id="audio"></audio>
```

Comment: Tried on Samsung phone (Chrome for Android), it doesn't work. See as well https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I played sound in one of my web project,
I had used JQuery, but you can modify it little bit to work in Javascript or instead use JQuery.

create a html tag audio and set the source of it.

```
<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

and fire a play method of audio using JQuery.

```
$('#chatAudio')[0].play();
```

I am not sure if it works for you or not. but you can try this way.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Chrome for Android. Does it work for you @GauravLad? Once again, this is the cause: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132

Comment: Actually it's been almost 8-9 months from now, when i used those code last time,

Comment: Still works: https://demos.9lessons.info/notify/index.html